# Configuration retrieving multiple config values Visual Studio 2015 C#6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, config.json

Trying to learn Visual Studio 2015 MVC and looking for some advice on how to retrieve multiple config values from config.json.

Currently I have the following:

```
public IEnumerable<WeatherConfigValues> WeatherAppSetting()
        {
            var con = new Configuration();
            con.AddJsonFile("Config.json");
            var weatherConfigSettings0 = con.Get("AppSettings:WeatherKey");
            var weatherConfigSettings1 = con.Get("AppSettings:Weather_FeedKey");

            var weatherConfigSettings = new List<WeatherConfigValues>
            {
                new WeatherConfigValues {WeatherKey         = weatherConfigSettings0},
                new WeatherConfigValues {WeatherFeedKey     = weatherConfigSettings1}
            };

            return weatherConfigSettings.ToList();
        }
```

Just ignore the names as I'm just trying to get code to work.

The above code does work and I can get the values in another class Library with the following:

```
var weatherSettings = new CustomConfigurationSettings();
            var getData         = weatherSettings.WeatherAppSetting().ToList();
            var test1           = getData[0].WeatherKey;
            var test2           = getData[1].WeatherFeedKey;
```

I have been looking at numerous websites such as http://blog.jsinh.in/asp-net-5-configuration-microsoft-framework-configurationmodel/#.VVYkyPlVhBd and http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/  but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the correct way, I tried **GetSubKeys** but that just returns null values.

So my question is, is this the correct way, or is there a correct way.

Comment: Why do you think this might not be the correct way?

Comment: @svick just seems a long way round to pull the data from config.json, thought there might be another way

Comment: The way you're representing the data is indeed overcomplicated (and unsafe). Is there any reason why you can't use just `return new WeatherConfigValues { WeatherKey = con.Get("AppSettings:WeatherKey"), WeatherFeedKey = con.Get("AppSettings:Weather_FeedKey") };`?